# How to make child form refresh when master is clicked?

Tags: ms-access

I have two tables, `WorkItem` and `Status`.  They are related as follows: `Status.WorkItemID` is the foreign key mapped to the primary key `WorkItem.ID`.  I want to set up a form so that there are datasheets for `WorkItem` and `Status`, and when a row in `WorkItem` is clicked, `Status` is refreshed with the related rows.

I tried doing this by opening the `WorkItem` table, and then creating a form based on it.  While this did create a form where going through the `WorkItem` records refreshes `Status`, `WorkItem` is represented as a set of text boxes rather than a datasheet, and I can't figure out how to change those text boxes to datasheets.

I also tried dragging `WorkItem` and `Status` tables onto a blank form, and then setting the properties for the form as follows:

- Record Source is set to "WorkItem"
- In the Table.Status control, Link Master Fields is set to "ID" and Link Child Fields is set to "WorkItemID"

This didn't link the two forms, though; all the rows in `Status` are listed, and when I click from one `WorkItem` row to another, nothing happens in the `Status` datasheet.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you open the form in Design View and set the Default View property to "Datasheet"?  When you open the Properties dialog box and click on the "Format" tab, it should be the second property from the top of the list.

Comment: I just tried that, but `WorkItem` is still showing as several text boxes--it didn't change into a datasheet.

Comment: I finally got this working, and this was part of the solution.